# Issue adding access token to header in Backbone: It changes the method

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I am using backbone to get data from an API.  This all works fine when there is no authorization required and when I add the authorization to the API, I get the expected 401 - unauthorised response.

[from the console log:

```
GET http://localhost:999/api/tasks 401 (Unauthorized)
```

]

I've then add in this code to add the bearer authorization to the header for every call:

```
var backboneSync = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.sync = function (method, model, options) {
    /*
     * The jQuery `ajax` method includes a 'headers' option
     * which lets you set any headers you like
     */

    var theUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("happuser"));

    if (theUser !== null)
    {
        var new_options =  _.extend({
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                var token = 'Bearer' + theUser.authtoken;
                console.log('token', token);
                if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
            }
        }, options) 
    }

    /*
     * Call the stored original Backbone.sync method with
     * extra headers argument added
     */
    backboneSync(method, model, new_options);
};
```

Once I include this code, the API sends the request with a method of OPTIONS instead of GET and I obviously get a 405 invalid method response.

Here is the console log output

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:999/api/tasks 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
OPTIONS http://localhost:999/api/tasks Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Any idea why the send method would be changing?

ADDITIONAL DISCOVERY:

It appears when I do a model.save it does the same thing., even if I don't actually change the model.

FURTHER DETAILS:  This is the Request/Response for the call without authorisation...

```
Request URL:http://localhost:999/api/tasks
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Host:localhost:999
Origin:http://localhost
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36

Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:3265
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 13 Nov 2013 14:51:32 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

As soon as I add the sync override code in the response changes to this:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:999/api/tasks
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Host:localhost:999
Origin:http://localhost
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36

Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost
Allow:GET,POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:76
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 13 Nov 2013 14:56:52 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to rename your `options` variable and see if the method changes to the new variable name.

Comment: In the backbone.sync method itself?

Comment: I might have removed too many things, but it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dDmk6/

Comment: @BenDrury yes, although that would need a new var; e.g. `var foo = options;` and use `foo` as the second parameter of `_.extend`. What I'm getting at is that the method is changed to OPTIONS, which is the name of the variable being passed in. If it sends FOO as the method, then that would be the problem. How you'd fix it would be another matter though...

Comment: I have added further info on the HTTP Get call.

Comment: @Harriyott...not it remains as OPTIONS and doesn't change to the new variable name, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @nikoshr I've updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/cogiva/G3mqS/) for collection as it is in my code, and you're right it works fine....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear you are issuing a "[not so simple request ™](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-handling-a-not-so-simple-request)":

- you're making a CORS request
- and you're setting a custom header

In that case, your browser divides your request in two : a preflight request (the OPTIONS verb you see) and the actual request once the permissions have been retrieved.

To quote the article linked:

> The preflight request is made as an HTTP OPTIONS request (so be sure
>   your server is able to respond to this method). It also contains a few
>   additional headers:
>
> *Access-Control-Request-Method* - The HTTP method of the actual request.
>   This request header is always included, even if the HTTP method is a
>   simple HTTP method as defined earlier (GET, POST, HEAD).
>
> *Access-Control-Request-Headers* - A comma-delimited list of non-simple
>   headers that are included in the request.
>
> The preflight request is a way of asking permissions for the actual
>   request, before making the actual request. The server should inspect
>   the two headers above to verify that both the HTTP method and the
>   requested headers are valid and accepted.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense... Thanks. I will get onto finding the fix.  How come it works fine as a CORS request if I don't amend the options?

Comment: Because if you don't set a custom header, the request is not preflighted (see _Handling a simple request_ in the article). And the fix would probably be to support the OPTIONS verb server side if you can.